# WoW Error#132, wont work with wine

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, wine

I am trying to run WoW on wine version 1.9.19 but it will simply not work, when I launch the WoW.exe I get an error 132.

I am trying to play on a private server (freakz) they had no installer, so im just running from where i downloaded it.

Comment: Many games, especially those with heavy graphics, require specific installation procedures.  You might do well to google for instructions on installing WoW under Wine -- it may work best with PlayOnLinux and a specific Wine version (as is the case with a couple online games I play).

Comment: There is no installation file for the server, when you download it its just a zip file with the whole game inside.

Comment: But on Windows you'd still have to "install" the game -- copying files to various system folders, setting registry flags and variables, and so forth.  That's normally done by the installer software, but that isn't working, so you likely have to make some specific settings in Wine to let the installer run.  Start with the appDB at winehq.com to see what they say about WoW under Wine, then look around for instructions on installing WoW in Ubuntu.  It's such a popular game, and Ubuntu is such a common distro, that there are almost certainly instructions *somewhere*.